# How to write into an excel from qliksense script?

Tags: qliksense

How to write into an excel from qliksense script?

I don't know how to write to excel from qliksense

Comment: please go through the proper guidelines before asking the question

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a csv, but not as an .xlsx extension.

```
Store <table> into [lib://Connection/FileName.csv](txt);
```